# Better way to search a list of objects in java

Tags: java

I have an object for servers with hostname and some sort of other fields. I'm searching my Database and get a `List<Server>`. So now I have another list of orders, which have besides some other fields a field for hostname.

At the moment I'm either iterating through list 1, get the hostname and then iterate trough list 2 and try to find the equal hostname, or I'm not making a list of servers but a `HashMap<Hostname, Server>` and look with contains if there is my hostname.

I want to know if there is a more elegant way to do this?

Comment: Do you also have the list of hostnames in the database? You could join the data in a SELECT statement. Otherwise, the `Map` is the ideal data structure for these kinds of lookups.

Comment: How long is the list?

Comment: a [mcve] would be helpful.

Comment: I would used a combination of `Map<Hostname, Server>` and `List<Server>`.  If the map contains the hostname, you have it.  Otherwise, search the `list` and if found, use it and also add to the map for the next round.

Comment: The downvote is not mine. However, please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: is your database SQL based?

Comment: The Info that a map ist ideal was all I wanted to know. Thanks for all the help and people who tried to make more out of the problem than it was.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question: when a map of objects with a key is the best way, then that ist all I need to know.

Comment: This is not a complete answer. And beside the fact that the question is unclear already, this is not helping others who might have similar issues.